# Backlogs and Links not completely migrating

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Good evening,

I have been playing with a test environment in preparation of a migration to get the configuration right.  Currently I have been unable to get the backlogs between the source and the target to match up correctly.  if I look at the source I see 19 User stories, 42 bugs, and 89 tasks on the backlog.  After the migration to the test environment I have 36 bugs in the backlog.
Also if I look at a variety work items, I am not seeing all the links having migrated over.  Now after the last run I have quite a few lines in the log that look like this:

```
[SKIP] Already Exists a Link of type System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse where wiSourceL=162, wiSourceR=156, wiTargetL=161, wiTargetR=155
```

I also have quite a few lines that look like:

```
[SKIP] Unable to migrate link where Link of type System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse where wiSourceL=53, wiSourceR=48, wiTargetL=53, wiTargetR=48 as target WI has not been migrated
```

yet I know that target work item exists.  I am doing a total of 5 runs on this configuration, by swapping which processors I am running during each run.  the last two runs are my final WorkItemMigrationConfig.  Does anyone see what I am missing?

Configuation.json

```
{
  "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://source.fdqn/Depreciated%20-%20MRM2%20Web%20App%20Development%20Team",
    "Project": "ProjectName",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "TfsMigrationTool.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://target.fdqn/TestWeb",
    "Project": "ProjectName",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      },
      "targetFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority",
      "targetField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank",
      "defaultValue": null
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "SourceToTargetMappings": {
        "SourceField1": "TargetField1",
        "SourceField2": "TargetField2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldValuetoTagMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked",
      "pattern": "Yes",
      "formatExpression": "{0}"
    },
  ],
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": false,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan') AND [System.Id] < 30",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.Id] asc, [System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": false,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    },
    {
        "$type": "TestConfigurationsMigrationConfig",
        "Enabled": false
    },
    {
        "$type": "TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationConfig",
        "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": false,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Plan') AND [System.Id] > 33 AND [System.Id] < 60 ",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.Id] asc, [System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": false,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    },  
    {
        "$type": "TestConfigurationsMigrationConfig",
        "Enabled": false
    },
    {
        "$type": "TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationConfig",
        "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": false,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Plan') AND [System.Id] > 59",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.Id] asc, [System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": false,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    },
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    }
  ],
  "Version": "11.9",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {    
    "Code Review Request": "Task",
    "Code Review Response": "Task",
    "Feedback Request": "Task",
    "Feedback Response": "Task",
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
      {
        "Name": "Source",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Target",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly normal for the tool to skip links. It migrates Work Items one at a time and if the linked work item does not exist yet then it will skip the link.

When it hits the other side of the link it will add a link back to the previously migrated item.

In the logs, you will see exactly how many work item are loaded as part of the migration.